# Javax Validation Implementation

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I am trying to create my custom annotation for local variables but I just don't understand how annotations like `@NotNull` or `@Null` are actually implemented in code. I looked at the actual file, here's `@NotNull`:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface NotNull {

    String message() default "{ javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message }";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        NotNull[] value();
    }
}
```

But I don't see anywhere where it checks to see if something is `null` or not. **Where is the actual check happening?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually you need to provide validatedBy class that is used for validation

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {TicketPresenceValidator.class})
public @interface AtLeastOneTicket {
}


public class TicketPresenceValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AtLeastOneTicket, TicketInfo> {
 @Override
 public void initialize(TicketInfo constraintAnnotation) {
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isValid(TicketInfo ticketInfo, 
                        ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return ticketInfo.getSize() != 0;
 }
}
```

For built-in constraints (from javax.validation.* package) like NotNull validators are provided by implementation library. For example Hibernate Validator implementation, here is

[NullValidator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/NullValidator.java) implementation

Then constraints and validators linked together in [helper class](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/db7ae586508add6491f1443c8ab4e770d7cb2c20/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/metadata/core/ConstraintHelper.java)

Comment: yeah i get that part, i actually made a custom annotation that uses that validator. But I'm wondering how specifically the `@NotNull` was implemented as I don't see any validators anywhere.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation for built-in constraints.

Answer (score 8):

> Where is the actual check happening?

If you look closely at - `javax.validation.constraints.@NotNull` source code ( that you have pasted ) , `@Constraint(validatedBy = { })` is left empty i.e. its not specified which would be implementation class. Its because javax validation jar like - `validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar` etc is basically a bean validation standard ( a set of interfaces , annotations etc with no implementation ). Implementation of these constraints is provided by vendors like hibernate , Oracle etc .

[This link](https://beanvalidation.org/specification/) lists three standards so you should know which version of bean validation standard you are using.

So if you have implementation jars like - `hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar` , you could see implementation source code too ,

```
/*
 * Hibernate Validator, declare and validate application constraints
 *
 * License: Apache License, Version 2.0
 * See the license.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0>.
 */
package org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * Validate that the object is not {@code null}.
 *
 * @author Emmanuel Bernard
 */
public class NotNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNull, Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return object != null;
    }
}
```

Now , you have to understand that searching / resolving for implementation of bean validation standard is a complex task , refer - `javax.validation.ValidationProviderResolver` & this process has been made easy if developer is using frameworks like Spring Boot etc.

Answer by inigo skimmer also does these two things - declares an annotation for your custom validation , implements the actual validation and resolves validator by hard coding validator class in - `@Constraint(validatedBy = {TicketPresenceValidator.class})` & that saves you from complex validation implementation searching logic.

The other part that you have to understand is that your validator is of type `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` so read javadoc as what you need to provide to [this interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html)

Other links to refer to ,

[Creating custom constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-compound)

[Create Your Own Constraints With Bean Validation 2.0](https://dzone.com/articles/create-your-own-constraint-with-bean-validation-20)